# Issues when upgrading Lenovo Ideapad Flex 2 14 with an SSD

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, ssd, bios, lenovo-laptop

After purchasing a Lenovo Ideapad Flex 2 14, I tried to upgrade it and replaced the HDD with an SSD from my older laptop. After putting in the SSD, I encountered a numerous amount of problems.

First, the Windows installation program didn't see the SSD, even the Diskpart utility didn't see it, so I decided to install Ubuntu instead, which was installed successfully. Everything was fine, but after messing around with the BIOS, the laptop wouldn't load the OS unless I first went into BIOS and exited it.

Windows still never saw the SSD, even after I installed Ubuntu on it and then tried to install Windows again. What could be the problem? Also, the HDD that came with this laptop works just fine, and the SSD works in another laptop just fine, too. The SSD is Intel 335 series 240GB. I'm gonna try to install Windows 7 a little later and see if that will work, but other than that I've already wasted an entire day trying to figure it out.

Comment: Sounds like a hairy one.  I wonder if the problem is related to UEFI booting - this has specific disk requirements, in addition to firmware requirements.  Can you turn off UEFI booting and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: @davigo that didn't help. Also right now if I start my computer it shows me some menu where I can choose what disk to load from, but regardless of whatever disk i choose, it still won't load it, it just restarts my computer and takes me back to the same menu. In order for me to turn my computer on I have to go to BIOS and switch my SATA controller mode from IDE to ACHI, if IDE was selected or ACHI to IDE, if ACHI was selected, this is extremely weird, think I'm gonna make another post on here.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/878162/weird-ssd-behavior-on-start-up here's the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there’s nothing you can do. The only SSD that will properly work is a Samsung SSD. So I’ll be buying one of those. I saw a thread on one of the forums dedicated to Lenovo, and somebody tried different SSDs and said that only Samsung worked. Here’s [that thread](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Yoga-Flex-Laptops-and/Flex-2-15-not-compatible-with-Intel-530-SSDs-how-to-remove-the/td-p/1707509).

**UPDATE:** I bought a samsung pro series ssd, and it works flawlessly!