# Lenovo IdeaPad Flex 2 won’t start up Windows directly from Intel 335 SSD

Tags: ssd, bios, sata, lenovo-laptop

I recently got a [Lenovo IdeaPad Flex 2 (14 inch)](http://shop.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/lenovo/flex-series/flex-2-14/) laptop and want to install an SSD  ([Intel 335 series 240gb SSD](http://www.anandtech.com/show/6388/intel-ssd-335-240gb-review)) from my old machine.

So, right now, whenever I start it, it takes me to a menu where it shows what storage device I want to load from. But regardless of whatever I choose it doesnt load anything, restarts my computer and takes me back to the same menu. In order for me to start Windows I have to go to the BIOS and change SATA controller mode from ACHI to IDE if ACHI was previously chosen or IDE to ACHI if IDE was previously chosen.

What can I do to fix this besides getting a new SSH?

Also, I updated my BIOS and it didn’t make any differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there's nothing you can do. The only SSD that will properly work is a Samsung SSD. So I'll be buying one of those. I saw a thread on one of the forums dedicated to Lenovo, and somebody tried different SSDs and said that only Samsung worked. Here’s [that thread](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Yoga-Flex-Laptops-and/Flex-2-15-not-compatible-with-Intel-530-SSDs-how-to-remove-the/td-p/1707509).

**UPDATE:** I bought a samsung pro series ssd, and it works flawlessly!